# tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath: Activity indicator not showing properly

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I am trying to show a activity indicatorvw when user taps on the cell of the table view it should show and as soon as detail view loaded it should be hidden.

But it is showing after view loaded and then hides. so it is useless to show indicator while view loads

Inside viewdidload:

```
activityBgImageView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
[activityBgImageView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
[activityBgImageView setAlpha:0.7];
[activityBgImageView setCenter:self.view.center];
[activityBgImageView setHidden:YES];

activityIndicatorView = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];
[activityIndicatorView setCenter:CGPointMake(self.view.center.x+15, self.view.center.y-15)];
[activityIndicatorView setHidesWhenStopped:YES];
[activityBgImageView addSubview:activityIndicatorView];
[self.view addSubview:activityBgImageView];
```

Here is my code for table did select:

```
if([arrPostsData count]>0)
{
    [self startActivityIndicatorView];

    [self performSelector:@selector(showDetailVw) withObject:nil];

}

-(void)showDetailVw
{

[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:.3];
detailVwBg.alpha = 0.0;
detailVwBg.alpha = 1.0;
btnBack.alpha = 1;

 [self showPostDetail:arrPostsData tapedCell:detailvwScrollCount     PostedFiles:arrUserPostedFilesDataDic comments:arrCommentsDataDic];

isDetailvwActive = TRUE;
[UIView commitAnimations];

}

and inside showPostDetail: method end i stop the indicator
```

Please suggest where I need to put correct code

these are indicator methods:

```
#pragma mark processindicator methods

-(void)startActivityIndicatorView{ 

[activityBgImageView setHidden:NO];
[activityIndicatorView startAnimating];
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:activityBgImageView];

if (![[UIApplication sharedApplication] isIgnoringInteractionEvents])
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginIgnoringInteractionEvents];
}


}

-(void)stopActivityIndicatorView{


if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] isIgnoringInteractionEvents])
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endIgnoringInteractionEvents];
}
[activityBgImageView setHidden:YES];
[activityIndicatorView stopAnimating];

}
```

Comment: Are you sure the user (and yourself) should be able to see the indicator being displayed for about 0.3 seconds ?

Comment: not able to see the indicator..

Comment: I was trying other then I was able..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A little bit of background about threads & iOS. For all UI elements to change (visually) the programmer needs to make changes to them in the main thread.

Since `activityIndicatorView` is a UI element, it has to run on main thread for it to display the spinning. If you are doing something else on your main thread then `activityIndicatorView` is blocked.  Hence you are not seeing the spinning instantaneously. You will see it when the thread is freed up.

If you want this to work then first start the spinner, then background thread, do processing in the bg thread, after it completes, come to main thread, stop spinner, and finally update the UI with the changes.

Hope this helps...

Comment: iOS Test, although Strikar answer might be a bit "overwhelming" it's correct answer. Do a bit of research of how to achieve this and play a bit with it, if you have more doubts, create another question, but make sure it's according to StackOverflow's defined FAQ.

Comment: Yes, if a person is new to iPhone development putting in place what you said can be though.

Comment: The principles of UI dev is the same iOS or Android or VisualBasic. Well, i probably was assuming too much. Added a few more notes/edits.

Comment: Srikar, I try to follow your answer and execute thread in background. now Spinner is seems visible but app crashed.. bcoz the background thread going to use UIKIT to change/create uicontrols.... CrashLog:bool _WebTryThreadLock(bool), 0xb2aa410: Tried to obtain the web lock from a thread other than the main thread or the web thread. This may be a result of calling to UIKit from a secondary thread. Crashing now... Please suggest how I need to deal this case.. I am creating some controls run time..it means I can not run that thread as bg thread...

Comment: you should not update UIKit elements from secondary thread. I though it made it clear. what you should do in secondary thread is purely non UIKit tasks, like some data processing, or some REST calls etc. after that task is done then comeback to the main thread & update uikit elements on main thread.

Comment: Srikar: I may be wrong to understand your point. So I am trying to explain my app Flow: I have a uitableview list, data populated initially from server JSON and display in uitable. I stored all server data in Array..now as per table cell index click, want to show the data in a detail view but I have all data in Array no Server call required for that, just accessing the array with index of table cell clicked by user. I created a detail uiview in view did load and make it hide. when user click the cell, this detail view appears, data from array will display here in run time created controls

Comment: ok i think i understood ur flow. how long does your flow take? it must be happening pretty fast, is it not? do you really need a spinner/`activityIndicatorView` here? think about it.

Comment: Srikar,Sometimes It required spinner. at detail view I am creating controls run time depends on the contents (subArray in main Array), actually at detail view I am creating uiwebview and image view over a scrollview in a for loop. loop runs the count of subarray (posted media files count). So when no meadia posted found or just one, detail view get visible very quickly then no spinner required. but in case  more than one media files/images founds then it takes time to get visible the detail view (if i resizing the image then it takes much more time) for such case i want to show a spinner.

Comment: why didnt you say you were using `uiwebview`? there are separate delegate methods reg. webView. the principles are the same. check this - http://blog.filipekberg.se/2010/12/01/displaying-a-loading-indicator-for-uiwebview-using-uiactivityindicatorview/.

Comment: Oh my bad... I did nt divert my mind this side.. Although i was familiar with uiwebview delegate.. Thanks Srikar